# VSCode jsconfig.json error "node_modules/agent-base/dist/src/index" not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-jsconfig

Why is VSCode showing this error?

It's just a jsconfig.json file.

**NOTE:** I'm not using TypeScript.

[image]

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try adding `"exclude": ["node_modules"]` as described in the [VSCode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_using-the-exclude-property).

I added this and restarted VSCode and the error message went away.

Comment: This worked. Restarting VSCode is very important in this case.

Comment: I had to include a slash for it work "node_modules/"

Comment: It's enough to restart the TS Server instead of restarting VS Code. Open the command palette and search for: `TypeScript: Restart TS Server`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Even including a slash like other users have suggested still doesn't work. And I properly restarted and everything.

Answer (score 6):

Disabling typescript in the workspace options seems to be the one thing that stopped this warning for me:

```
"typescript.validate.enable": false,
```

Comment: The only response that actually fixed it for me. Thanks Steve!

Answer (score 1):

Add `"exclude": [ "node_modules/**/*", ]`, in the `tsconfig.json` file and if it still doesn't work, try reloading the VSCode by pressing `Crtl + Shift + P` and Reload Window and it should work.

Comment: It's damn correct, worth thousand likes!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the issue in `Vuejs/Nuxtjs` project:

1. Check the `jsconfig.json` file in root and include the following things if not available already:
   `"exclude": ["node_modules"]`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6",
      "baseUrl": "."
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
  }
```

**Important**

2. If you are getting the error even after having these values then you SHOULD RESTART vs code application

Answer (score -2):

I also had some issues like this while using node modules. I just recreated the project copied and pasted all the code that i needed and installed every node modules after that i was able to fix the issue. However i dont recommend for large projects.

Comment: I found I need a slash in the path for this to work:  `"exclude": ["node_modules/"]`

Comment: Just FYI, this not considered as solution, it's a workaround that solved your problem by chance!.